# Java: reading content from text file to create an object?

Tags: java, file

I am attempting to read from a text file similar to:

```
exampleName1 exampleAddress1
exampleName2 exampleAddress2
```

How can I create an object with the name and address together by reading each line in a text file?

```
E.g: Record record1= new Record(name, address);
```

I have attempted to use `Scanner` but I am not sure how to exactly.

```
Scanner myscanner= new Scanner (new FileInputStream(myfile.txt);

while (myscanner.hasnext()){

//read from file?

}

//create object here...
```

Comment: *I have attempted to use Scanner * post what your have attempted and where is the problem

Comment: I have done so with my edit

Comment: So you have **attempted nothing** and you want some spoon feeding?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner myscanner= new Scanner (new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
while (myscanner.hasnext()){
  String line = myscanner.readline();
  int index = line.indexOf(' ');
  String name = line.substring(0, index-1);//TODO check...
  String address = line.substring(index);
  records.add(new Record(name, address);
}
```

Untested code, but should work (somehow). If you have problems, be more specific with the question.

Edit: of course the scanner has not readline(). Btw. why use a Scanner? With a BufferedReader and a proper InputStreamReader you can do it.

Edit2:
With proper I mean, that you pass the Charset of the file like this: `new InputStreamReader("filename", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` (or whatever the Charset of the file is...)

Comment: well you are provided with the logic of how you can achieve what you want, in case you want exact piece code you should try understand the `Scanner` api and see which methods can be used. for example here `readline` means `nextLine()` and `hasnext()` means `hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please search a little bit much more to find out such a simple answer...

[Cave of Programming exemple](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html)

I would try something like this :

```
try {
    String line;
    String[] splitedLine;
    String name;
    String address;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        splitedLine = line.split(' ');
        name = splitedLine[0];
        address = splitedLine[1];
        new Record(name,address);
        //You could also do new Record(splitedLine[0],splitedLine[1]);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```